# If $a$ is a real number and $f(x) = x^5 - 5x + a$, then how does the value of a influence the number of roots of f(x).

Tags: calculus, inequality, roots, graphing-functions

My book gives this question and in the solution does it following:

> Let $y = x^5-5x$. Then $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 5(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1).$$ By finding the signs of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in various intervals, it concludes that $x = -1$ is local maximum and $x = 1$ is local minimum. At these points $y$ is equal to $4$ and $-4$ respectively.

Now it says that since $y = -a$, $f(x)$ has three real roots as per the graph, when $a$ is in the range $(-4,4)$. However when $a$ is less than $-4$ or greater than $4$, $f(x)$ has one real root.
Why is this so? If $y = -a$ or $a = -y$, and $y$ lies in the range $(-4,4)$, how can a cross this range? And what does this diagram indicate, and where are the roots in the diagram?[image]

Comment: A hint:  The graph of $y=x^5-5x+a$ is just the graph of $y=x^5-5x$ shifted upward $a$ units (if $a >0$).  Incidentally, when you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) your posts will become much more legible, and there will be more chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagram looks like a graph of $x^5 - 5x$.  So, the case when $a = 0$.  It is slightly unusual that the $y$ axis is not drawn and there are no grid lines but it still helps.

[image]

It shows you that for most of the time, the function is increasing but it has a "wobble" around $0$.  It also illustrates the local maximum and minimum that you found.

Changing the value of $a$ will add or subtract uniformly from the value of $y$ and hence it will just move the graph up or down.  From the picture, it should be clear that if $a = 4$ (graph moved up by $4$) then the local minimum at $x = 1$ will just touch the the $x$ axis.  If $a > 4$ then it will no longer touch and you will have *lost* a root.  Similarly, if $a = -4$ (graph moved down by $4$) then the local maximum at $x = -1$ will now just touch the $x$ axis.  If $a < -4$ then you will *lose* that root.

Redraw the graph with several values of $a$ e.g. $-6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6$ and see what happens to the roots.  You will always have one but sometimes you will have two or three.

This behaviour is very typical of cubic polynomials (maximum power power of $x$ is $3$).  Quintic (power $5$) polynomials can be more complicated (up to $5$ roots) but this set is simpler than the general quintic.

Comment: By losing a root, do you mean that if a <-4 or a>4 there is no root at all? How will there be a single root?

Comment: @Hema : Any (real) polynomial of odd degree will always have at least one real root.

Comment: @Hema By "losing a root", I just meant that one goes. not all.  That would be "losing all roots".  Later, I said "You will always have one but sometimes you will have two or three" so, as Lutzl says, you will always have at least one (real) root.  On the "real", I decided not to mention complex roots.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for adding the graph.